# How to make button disabled after reaching 1 in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In typescript code I tried to disable the "-" button in the Shopping Cart if amount of item = 1.

Currently, when clicking the "-" button we can reach amount 0, -1, -2 etc. I tried to disable it using jQuery and JS code, but in result received only mistake.

Could you please help with answer how to make it work properly?

```
import {
    CardContent,
    CardActions,
    Button,
    Card,
    TextField,
} from '@mui/material'
import { Component } from 'react'
import './ProductListItem.scss'

type Props = {
    title: string
    description: string
    type: string
    capacity: string
    price: number
    image: string
}

type State = {
    count: number
}

class ProductListItem extends Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count: 1,
        }
        this.onIncrementClick = this.onIncrementClick.bind(this)
        this.onDecrementClick = this.onDecrementClick.bind(this)
    }
    onIncrementClick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            count: prevState.count + 1,
        }))
    }

    onDecrementClick() {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            count: prevState.count - 1,
        }))
    }

    render() {
        const { title, description, type, capacity, price, image } = this.props
        return (
            <Card variant="outlined" className="product">
                <CardContent>
                    <div className="product-image">
                        <img src={image} alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="product-title">{title}</div>
                    <div className="product-description">{description}</div>
                    <div className="product-features">Type:{type}</div>
                    <div className="product-features">Capacity:{capacity}</div>
                    <div className="product-price">Price:{price}</div>
                    <div className="product-quantity">
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            onClick={this.onDecrementClick}
                        >
                            -
                        </Button>
                        <TextField size="small" value={this.state.count} />
                        <Button
                            variant="outlined"
                            onClick={this.onIncrementClick}
                        >
                            +
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions className="btns-wrap">
                    <Button variant="outlined">Add to cart</Button>
                </CardActions>
            </Card>
        )
    }
}

export default ProductListItem
```

Expacting to receive result like code below, but in TS

```
 let input = document.querySelector(".input");
let button = document.querySelector(".button");

button.disabled = true;

input.addEventListener("change", stateHandle);

function stateHandle() {
    if (document.querySelector(".input").value === "") {
        button.disabled = true;
    } else {
        button.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: MUI have prop which called disabled. add this to your button.                                    disabled={this.state.count.length === 0}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to add event listeners and such. You can do this by using the `disabled` prop as written on the [MUI Button props documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#props) and passing the `count` state as a check.

```js
<Button
  variant="outlined"
  onClick={this.onDecrementClick}
  disabled={this.state.count === 1}
>
  -
</Button>
```